# bash substitute first character in every line

Tags: bash, sed

My file looks like this:

```
  1 chrX_73833098_73834098
  1 chrX_73889652_73890652
  1 chrX_91194501_91195501
  1 chrX_92000157_92001157
  1 chrX_92106500_92107500
```

I want to replace first character "1" into 0. Wanted output is :

```
  0 chrX_73833098_73834098
  0 chrX_73889652_73890652
  0 chrX_91194501_91195501
  0 chrX_92000157_92001157
  0 chrX_92106500_92107500
```

Trying to do it with this:

```
sed 's/^./0/g' file
```

But the output is:

```
0     1 chrX_73833098_73834098
0     1 chrX_73889652_73890652
0     1 chrX_91194501_91195501
0     1 chrX_92000157_92001157
0     1 chrX_92106500_92107500
```

I believe there is easy way to fix it, but I don't know it.

Comment: You have `white-spaces` at the beginning of every line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is whitespace character at the begging of each line.

you can try:

```
sed 's/^\s*./0/g' file
```

\s  - match white space characters

output:

```
0 chrX_73833098_73834098
0 chrX_73889652_73890652
0 chrX_91194501_91195501
0 chrX_92000157_92001157
0 chrX_92106500_92107500
```

if you want to preserve whitespace characters:

```
sed 's/^\(\s*\)\(1\)/\10/g' file
```

I also have replaced here . with 1

Comment: You don't need to anchor the pattern at the beginning of the line: just use `sed 's/[[:digit:]]/0/' file` that only changes the first digit. To change the first non-space character, `s/[^[:space:]]/0/`.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is an easy way to understand.
Try:

```
sed 's/1/0/1' file
```

output:

```
1 chrX_73833098_73834098
1 chrX_73889652_73890652
1 chrX_91194501_91195501
1 chrX_92000157_92001157
1 chrX_92106500_92107500
```

I want to say that the 's/partten/partten/g', the last 'g' mean the place in a line.
'1' mean the first matched, 'g' means all, also you can use '2g' which means from second to last.
Have a try.

Comment: Really like this one, came here again just to realize I had already voted up