# How to quickly rename my files on macOS or linux from CLI?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, scripting, rename

Here're my source files.

```
e2f9eb91-645f-408a-9241-66490b61a617_file-module-1.txt
d20f06a8-4de1-4da0-8175-93e9b2d81c42_file-module-2.txt
6740a19f-e1a0-43da-9a01-9e873238360e_file-module-3.txt
.
.
.
```

I need to figure it out a way to rename all the files to remove the first 36 characters up to _file or replacing as something else. I am expecting all the files  are as below.

```
_file-module-1.txt or Yong_file-module-1.txt
_file-module-2.txt or Yong_file-module-2.txt
_file-module-3.txt or Yong_file-module-3.txt
.
.
.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Second time this question was asked today.  Here's how to ask a question which will get an answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Research the web first, find common questions answered.  Show an attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569389/renaming-a-file-in-bash-using-regular-expressions/569400#569400

Comment: A possibility could be to write a C program or a Python script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rename` like this:

```
rename --dry-run 's/.*_file/Yong_file/' *.txt
```

---

If you are on macOS, you can install `rename` with **homebrew**:

```
brew install rename
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! This is exactly what I am looking for. .*_file

Comment: Cool, feel free to upvote it and accept it as the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use mac, you can simply try this via UI:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/guide/mac-help/mchlp1144/mac

Or if you want to try those work via CLI:
https://www.howtogeek.com/423214/how-to-use-the-rename-command-on-linux/
(read from **Renaming Multiple Files with mv**)

This might help also; sed commands of linux:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/

and another stackoverflow article: [bash substitute first character in every line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140213/bash-substitute-first-character-in-every-line)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I could not find a way to get it done in an automated way for all the files. Basically, I am looking for how to replace the first 36 characters of all these files from CLI.

Comment: @Yong You can checkout crontab for automated ways.
I can't help you make the 36 characters completely, but this stackoverflow article might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140213/bash-substitute-first-character-in-every-line
Plus I edited my answer so please checkout.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these links, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this would be to use a combination of [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find), [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) and [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs).

```
find . -name '*.txt' | sed 'p;s/.*_file/Yong_file/' | xargs -n2 mv
```

This finds text files in the current working directory, echoes the original file name (`p`) and then a modified name (`s/.*_file/Yong_file/`) and feeds it all to `mv` in pairs (`xargs -n2`).

Answer (score 0):

If you would use **zsh**, you could do a

```
 autoload zmv # Because zmv is not active by default
 zmv '????????????????????????????????????(*module*txt)' '_$1'
```

Since you want to use **bash**, you could steal it from zsh and use it within bash like this:

```
zsh -c "autoload zmv; zmv '????????????????????????????????????(*module*txt)' '_$1'"
```

(These should be 36 question marks; better you count them again instead of blindly copying this code).

Comment: @Yong: May I ask you then to accept my anwer?

Comment: I'm a newbie. Let me figure it out how to accept the answers.

Comment: Click on the checkmark next to the answer.  See  [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow)