# bash: remove all defined characters from the ensemble of the filles

Tags: bash, sed

I am working with the folder contained the ensemble of the filles with the following names:

```
(base) Glebs-MacBook-Pro:laura_2 enrico$ ls -t
structure_36_S.mol2 structure_31_R.mol2 structure_23.mol2
structure_36_R.mol2 structure_30_S.mol2 structure_22.mol2
structure_35_S.mol2 structure_30_R.mol2 structure_21.mol2
structure_35_R.mol2 structure_29_R.mol2 Structure_20R.mol2
structure_34_S.mol2 structure_28_R.mol2 Structure_19R.mol2
structure_34_R.mol2 structure_27_R.mol2 Structure_13R.mol2
structure_33_S.mol2 structure_26.mol2   +
structure_33_R.mol2 structure_25.mol2
structure_32_R.mol2 structure_24.mol2
```

as you see all of the mol2 filles contains one or two "*" (under-score) characters in their names. Could you suggest me some command in linux which will remove all "*" from all of those filles at one. I used find + sed:

```
find . -name '*.mol2' | sed 'p;s/_//' | xargs -n2 mv
```

but in that case I had to use it twisely for the files contained two _ . May this code be modified ?

Comment: I would use `rename` - example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67530527/2836621

Comment: That said, if your goal is interactive shell usage rather than script development, questions are better asked at [unix.se] rather than here regardless. On Stack Overflow, we prefer to prioritize robust, reliable, readable, maintainable code over _terse_ code; playing "code golf" to eliminate characters at the expense of quality brings a question away from being _practical_, as the Help Center definition of our scope requires.